# Example of real valued function that is not integrable on compact

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a measurable function which is not bounded but, finite-valued. How can it not integrable on a compact interval?

I am thinking finite $\times$ finite = finite, if we look at it from a maximum $\times$ length perspective

Comment: There's no reason the function should be bounded on compact sets.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich indeed, but I still fail to understand why it fails or to find a good example of such a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an example, consider the function defined on the unit interval $[0,1]$:
$$f(0)=0,\; and \;f(x)=n(n+1),\; for \;x\in(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}],\;n\in\mathbb{Z}_+.$$

Comment: Thanks, I suppose this boils down to what is a convergent series.